SELECT Anidado, guardar valor y no ID
Hola estoy trabajando en un option select anidado de 2 niveles, funciona correctamente al desplegar cada select el unico detalle es que no me guarda los valores ejemplo (Medellin, Cali, Bogota) sino los ID (1,2,3) Espero su ayuda gracias.
CODIGO JS y PHP
    <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#departamento").change(function () {
                    
                    $("#departamento option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_estado = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getMunicipio.php", { id_estado: id_estado }, function(data){
                            $("#ciudad").html(data);
                        });         
                    });
                })
            });
            
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#ciudad").change(function () {
                    $("#ciudad option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_municipio = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getLocalidad.php", { id_municipio: id_municipio }, function(data){
                            $("#corregimiento").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>


<form action="signup-user.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                    
<div class="form-group pt-1">
    <label class="h6 text-gris text-weight">Departamento</label>
    <select class="form-control border-color" name="departamento" id="departamento" value="<?php echo $departamento ?>">
        <option value="0">Seleccionar Departamento</option>
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_estado']; ?>"><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
                    
<div class="form-group pt-1">
    <label class="h6 text-gris text-weight">Ciudad</label>
    <select class="form-control border-color" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="<?php echo $ciudad ?>">
    </select>
</div>

<button id="registrarNuevo" type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="signup" class="btn btn-primary width-btn fs-5 mr-3" data-loading-text="Getting Few Sec..." >Registrar</button>

</form>


Revisaste que tu consulta realmente devuelva el nombre del estado y no nuevamente el id del estado? Por lo demás parece estár correcto.
